# prototype cell is too big (xcode)

Tags: xcode

There is a problem in the prototype cell (look the picture).

This is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    groupsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"groupCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Group *gr = [myGroupsListData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.groupName.text = gr.name;
   [cell.groupImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:gr.imageName]];
    return cell;
}
```

http://postimg.org/image/lr1wh0mth/

Comment: I guess that groupsTableViewCell represent a cell with a reference to a IB picture and text, if that's correct then you can adjust the cell manually in the storyboard to the exact height you need. 2nd option is to call tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: (UITableViewDelegate) but I wouldn't use it if you can do it in the storyboard.
Also, next time please use google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563373/how-to-change-the-height-of-table-view-cell and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252628/how-to-increase-the-height-of-the-cell-in-a-tableview-in-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure Row Height in Attribute inspector for TableView and TableViewCell is same.

[image]

[image]