# Table view cell size

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am using Xcode with objective C.

(I think) I successful create a table view and created a new cell with all connections.
The problem is the size of the cell in runtime. I create a bigger cell,  with 2 labels (1 top and 1 bottom), can only see the top label. 
[image: Screen shot]

Sorry if is repost, didn't find one solution, and thanks.

Comment: You are more likely going to get a response, and helpful information, if you include your code that is not working, or approaches that you have attempted but have failed.

Comment: You need to change the height of your table view cells. Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563373/how-to-change-the-height-of-table-view-cell

Comment: I presume you know you should be using constraints to set the layout of your views in a storyboard. But table views are a bit weird, implement the delegate method heightForRowAtIndexPath and return your cell height in there.

Comment: You were really fast. I tried the method of beyowulf, and worked. I don't understand why it can't use the real size of the prototype cell.

Comment: Because different cells from single prototype can have different heights

Answer (score 0):

You must also implement the method `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and return the height that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this UITableView delegate method:

```
-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

      // return the desired height of your cell
      return 80.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to edit options for both the cell and the tableview controller: 
[TableView Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGKih.png), 
[CellView options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV6JG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one. It may be helpful to you

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
      CGSize constraintSize = {245.0, 20000}
      CGSize neededSize = [ yourText sizeWithFont:[UIfont systemFontOfSize:14.0f] constrainedToSize:constraintSize  lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap]
        if ( neededSize.height <= 18) 

          return 45
    else return neededSize.height + 45 
    //18 is the size of your text with the requested font    (systemFontOfSize 14). if you change fonts you have a different number to use  
    // 45 is what is required to have a nice cell as the neededSize.height is the "text"'s height only
    //not the cell.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom TableView Cell

Method[image]

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 105;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in tableViewdelegate (assumed using autolayout) :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

}

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```